# Node Version Manager (NVM) managed node.js instance "JavaScript heap out of memory" error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Node Version Manager on both Linux and Windows 10.

```
nvm list

10.16.3
* 8.11.3 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
```

I currently use the Node.js version 8.11.3 and encountered following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x12190dc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
```

As per various suggested methods on StackOverflow, I tried to increase the `--max-old-space-size` parameter via environment variables on both Linux and Windows but it did not help.

Has anyone encountered this issue with NVM managed Node.js instance and successfully resolved it?

Comment: When does this error occur? When running `nvm list`? When executing some script?

Comment: @Mureinik -  error occurs when a particular functionality of the application is invoked. That functionality gathers data from the DB and exports it into the Excel file.

Comment: It's very unlikely this error has anything to do with NVM, but probably with the function in question. Can you share its code?

Comment: Try removing and redownloading that particular version through NVM, sounds like a bad download.

Comment: @Mureinik - please see the code here --> https://www.codepile.net/pile/V67ayqPa

Comment: @Mureinik I think you're right about the issue related to the underlying function itself. 3rd line results in 760.000 lines of JSON data being fetched from the DB which is a lot.

Comment: Can you try Node v12? I had a same problem with Node v11 and switching to 12 fixed it, maybe in your case it works as well?

Comment: @onuriltan Unfortunately upgrading Node.js did not work! :(

Comment: Is this failing without nvm? Just using node in your environment?

Comment: @onuriltan I have installed latest stable version of Node.js via NVM but it didn't help. I believe I need to change the code.